# Is there any way to convert an object to an array in mongodb without using $objectToArray or $function?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I am using mongodb from Atlas and with the subscription we have, we are not able to use $objectToArray or $function methods on it. Is there any way to convert an object that looks like:

```
{
  "a": {
    "prop1": "val1",
    "prop2": "val2"
  },
  "b": {
    "prop3": "val4"
  }
}
```

to

```
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "prop1": "val1",
    "prop2": "val2" 
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "prop3": "val4"
 } 
]
```

*This array being the final result data from the query.

Comment: You can write a function inside the query if you must

Comment: Why can't you use objectToArray?

Comment: Altas isn't allowing me to write functions either.

Comment: @Gibbs $objectToArray is not allowed in this atlas tier' on server 'devmongodb-shard-xx.mongodb.net'

Comment: I see in the documentation that some Atlas tiers do not allow server-side javascript (e.g., `"$function"`), but I couldn't find a `"$objectToArray"` restriction.  Do you have a link to this restriction?  What error message is returned if you try to use it?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I have copy pasted the error from the mongo terminal, this is not a theoretical assumption.

Comment: Wow, that's disappointing.  Even the free tier on Atlas allows `"$objectToArray"`.  :-(